# Add Custom UIMenuController in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I want to highlight some sentence inside the TextEditor by giving selection on the text, then I want a new custom UIMenuController but in Swift UI, I've followed some tutorial and it works in UIKit but it can't appear when I try to implement in inside swiftUI using UIRepresentable, any ideas to add that custom UIMenuController in SwiftUI?

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate 
{
        var text: Binding<String>
        var model: ScriptField_Model
        
        init(_ text: Binding<String>, _ model: ScriptField_Model) {
            self.text = text
            self.model = model
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.text.wrappedValue = textView.text
            self.model.text = textView.text
        }
        
        func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
            let menuItem1: UIMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Menu 1", action: #selector(onMenu1(sender:)))
            // Store MenuItem in array.
            let myMenuItems: [UIMenuItem] = [menuItem1]
            
            // Added MenuItem to MenuController.
            UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = myMenuItems
            UIMenuController.shared.hideMenu()
        }
        
        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
            return true
        }
        
        @objc internal func onMenu1(sender: UIMenuItem) {
            print("onMenu1")
        }
    }
```

this is the part i try to add when select the sentence :

```
func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
            let menuItem1: UIMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Menu 1", action: #selector(onMenu1(sender:)))
            // Store MenuItem in array.
            let myMenuItems: [UIMenuItem] = [menuItem1]

            // Added MenuItem to MenuController.
            UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = myMenuItems
            UIMenuController.shared.hideMenu()
        }
```

Any Help and reference, i will appreciate it.. thankyouu

Answer (score 1):

first create class like CVEDictTextView

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
class CVEDictTextView: UITextView {
    
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        let newInstanceItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Lookup", action:#selector(lookup))
        UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [newInstanceItem]
        UIMenuController.shared.hideMenu()
        if(action == #selector(lookup)){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    @objc func lookup() {
        if(self.selectedRange.location != NSNotFound ){
            let str = self.value(forKey: "text") as! String
            var str2 = String(str.dropFirst(self.selectedRange.location))
            str2 =    String(str2.dropLast(str2.count - self.selectedRange.length))
            print(str2)
        }
    }
}
```

and create TextView UIViewRepresentable

```
struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var textStyle: UIFont.TextStyle
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = CVEDictTextView()
        
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: textStyle)
        textView.autocapitalizationType = .sentences
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textView.isEditable = false
        
        return textView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        uiView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: textStyle)
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator($text)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var text: Binding<String>
        
        init(_ text: Binding<String>) {
            self.text = text
            
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.text.wrappedValue = textView.text
            
        }
    }
}
```

in SwitfUI view
using it

```
@State private var message = "hello how are you \n\t are you ok? email : hung.phuoc.tran@gmail.com"
@State private var textStyle = UIFont.TextStyle.body
TextView(text: $message, textStyle: $textStyle)
    .padding(.horizontal)
```